# Swift 1.2 -> NSSet -> incompatible type

Tags: ios, swift

OK, what's going on with Swift 1.2? I recently updated and suddently my project is all red. Has the compatibility with NSSets been removed or what? How do I fix this?

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
```

results to:

```
Overriding method with selector 'touchesBegan:withEvent:' has incompatible type '(NSSet, UIEvent) -> ()'
```

Answer (score 5):

Please not that NNsets is now being declared as :

```
 func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent)
```

Please try the below code for overriding

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<NSObject>, withEvent event: UIEvent) {

        // ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change NSSet to Set. Swift now has its own native sets and bridges NSSets to them just like it does Arrays and Strings.